# Xbee S2 link failing after random periods

Tags: serial-port, arduino, usb, xbee, ftdi

I am using a pair of Xbee S2 modules in AT mode to transfer data at 9600 from an Arduino to an WinXP PC via an FTDI USB converter. The PC is running a charting program that polls the serial stream, the Arduino is running code that listens for and responds to the polling. The system may run perfectly for a day or so, occasionally for a week, occasionally for 1 hour, then the polling requests from the PC stop being sent.  The Arduino end just sits there waiting for a command. I tried increasing Baud rate to 38,400 across the system and if anything, it was worse.

I discovered the Digi.com notes online which describe optimizing the USB to serial port settings by reducing packet size and latency to minimum settings and while this may have made some improvement, it certainly hasn’t solved the problem. I’m left scratching my head about what to try next. Any ideas please?
Michael

Comment: If you restart from the polling end without restarting the other end does it start working properly again? If so you may want to upload some code to see if there is some big that can be caught from that end. Of not you may need to provide even more details.

Comment: How much data are you sending?  Have you enabled hardware flow control to ensure that neither host sends when its local XBee module's buffers are full?  As @djUniversal said -- try resetting just one XBee or the other to isolate the problem as occurring on the PC's XBee or the Arduino's.  If resetting XBee modules doesn't solve it, try resetting the program on each end to see if it's a failure in your host code.